# Power Automate - Send multiple emails with partial data from Excel

Tags: power-automate

How do I send an email for each person listed in an Excel table with the corresponding lines for each?

In this example there are 5 lines and I would like to send the data from the first 3 lines to one person and the last two lines to a different person.

[image: TableSample]

I have created flows that pull data and send one email using 'List rows in a table' and 'Compose Email' but I'm lost when it comes to filtering the data and sending multiple emails.  I'm familiar with 'Apply to Each', but that would send an email for each line of the table. I need to group the data and send one email per person with only the lines assigned to them.